# I want to load a gif image when user clicks on logout and then redirects to home page. i am trying to do using php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, gif

I have a page(era.php) which has a logout option. When user clicks on logout, it calls logout.php which destroys session and has header too index:
header('Location: index.php');
This all is working fine. But, i want some gif image to be loaded when user clicks on logout and then it redirects to index.
It is very quick now...actually i want to add some delay which shows some image saying Redirecting.. something.

Comment: I do not know, if there is a 'php'-way of doing it, but in pure HTML/js, I wold do it the following way: (1) Put an invisible container with the gif to the correct position in the HTML. (2) Add a click listener to the logout button, that sets the container from step 1 visible. (3) Handle the redirect (maybe after some delay) afterwards.

Comment: Why would you want to delay the redirection? You could show the "logged out" message on the redirect: index.php. The user doesn't need a "redirecting..." message when there is no delay in redirecting anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a logout.php as a middleman, without header redirection and do any action in that page.

E.g. removing the current session, showing an html message and redirecting with javascript after x seconds.

**Update:** You can use the a meta tag to refresh the page. [W3C page](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H76.html)

Comment: Can you please elaborate this method? I cant figure out how to do this using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this and is working although:
When a user clicks on "logout" load.php is loaded:
Here it is:(i have passed Get request because if user tries to open load.php through url)
**load.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id']) || !isset($_SESSION['user_name']) ||   !isset($_SESSION['user_right']))
    header('Location: .');
if(isset($_GET['val']))
{
 if($_GET['val']=='out')
 { 
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Redirecting..</title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="margin: 250px 0px 0px 600px;">
    <div>
        <img src="img/301.gif">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<?php
  header("refresh:5;url=logout");
  }
}
else
 header('Location:.');
?>
```

And, then logout.php destroys session and calls the index.